# Was there any trouble on the exam? / Were there any difficulties on the exam? / Were there any problems on the exam?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm confused about these sentences. What's the difference? Which one is more common?  Why is "difficulties" used rarely in this context? (I've noticed it on the internet.)

> **Was there any trouble** on the exam?
>
> **Were there any difficulties** on the exam?
>
> **Were there any problems** on the exam?

Comment: If you replace **on** with **with** or **in**, all are possible although people are more likely to ask: **Did you have any trouble/difficulties/problem(s) with the exam?**

Comment: I would say that all three are equally common, including this usage of "difficulty." I would say there are no significant differences in their meanings.